# The character encoding specified in the HTTP header (iso-8859-1) is different from the value in the <meta> element (utf-8)

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I have developed a GWT / GAE application and trying to have it indexed by Google. In order to check first that my home page is 100% clean, I am using the W3C validation service to check the syntax.

The validation service is returning an error regarding the character encoding mismatch as follows :

"The character encoding specified in the HTTP header (iso-8859-1) is different from the value in the `<meta>` element (utf-8). I will use the value from the HTTP header (iso-8859-1) for this validation."

Could you please help me on this one :

- On the development environment, the file is stored in utf-8, so I was
  expecting that the web server would return the file also with
  character encoding utf-8. I am pretty sure it is utf-8 after
  verifying the character encoding on osx with the following command :
  "file -I HOME_PAGE_NAME.jsp" which returned "HOME_PAGE_NAME.jsp:
  text/html; charset=utf-8"
- Is there anything I should do to have the file delivered with the
  correct character encoding ?

Thanks,

Hugues

Comment: you may need to explain the web architecture you are using.

Comment: Hi Jean-Michel, thanks for the feedback. The web server is Google App Engine. Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Not really, it's because you've mentioned JSP files

Comment: Hi, the home page is a .jsp file. Do you think that could be the source of the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure your JSP files are encoded as `UTF-8`.

And be sure your JSP pages includes this header :

```java
<%@ page pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

Plus, to be sure, I would also add this to your GWT html files :

```html
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: Hi Jean-Michel, you were right. The only thing I had to change was "<@" had to be replaced by "<%@". Thanks for your help !

Comment: Of course, I've added to the answer. Thanks for pointing that out